# Why does the array of elements not get printed under sprintf as below in the code?

Tags: arrays, c, printf

// Example program to demonstrate sprintf() by usage of an array.

I am new to c and trying to master the idea of sprintf functioning with an array.
Why does the program fail, or instead print the errors instead of the array d elements?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char buffer[50];

    char d[5]= {1,2,3,4,5};
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=6; i++)
    {
        sprintf(buffer[i], "\n num : %s ", i);
    }
   
 
    // The string "sum of 10 and 20 is 30" is stored
    // into buffer instead of printing on stdout
    for(i=0; i<=6; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %s", buffer[i]);
    }
   
 
    return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting the error as below..

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:13:17: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘sprintf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         sprintf(buffer[i], "\n num : %s ", i);
                 ^
In file included from main.c:2:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:364:12: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern int sprintf (char *__restrict __s,
            ^
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: In this call sprintf(buffer[i], "\n num : %s ", i); at least buffer[i] does not point to an array.. It is a scalar object of the type char. This call entirely does not make a sense.

Comment: And nowhere in the program you are using the array d.

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf` expects its first parameter to have type `char *` and to be the *address* of the first element of an array large enough to hold the resulting string.  However, in the line

```
sprintf(buffer[i], "\n num : %s ", i);
```

`buffer[i]` is a *single character* of type `char`, not an array of `char`.

As declared, `buffer` can hold a *single* string up to 49 characters long (at least one element must be reserved for the string terminator).  As written, your code is expecting to generate and print 7 different strings, so `buffer` will need to be declared as

```
char buffer[7][50]; // hold up to 7 strings of up to 49 characters each
```

With that change your code should work as you expect.

Comment: It shows a segmentation fault in that case.

Comment: @kaylee_96: was that before or after my edit - I didn't notice you were looping from 0 to 6, so you need a 7x50 array.

Comment: after your edit. I did edit my code to involve the usage of the variable 'd' as i noticed it wasn't being used in my program, but I am not sure on how I should involve to store the elements of d to the buffer.

Comment: @kaylee_96: Bah, I'm blind in my old age - in the `sprintf` call you need to use `%d` instead of `%s` because `i` is an `int`.  The `%s` is telling `sprintf` to interpret `i` as an *address*, and those values are not valid addresses.  Sorry about that.

Comment: It got resolved, got a better understanding, thanks.